# Multirow does not work in tabu

Tags: tables, multirow, tabu

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabu}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tabu} to \textwidth { X[2,c] | X[3,c]}
     \toprule
     C1 &  C2 \\
     \tabucline
     \multirow{3}{*}{What Happened} & This is row 1 \\
                                    & This is row 2\\ 
                                    & This is row 3 \\
     \bottomrule
     \end{tabu}
\end{document}
```

[image]

`\multirow` does not seem to work at all. Where's the problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`multirow` works as usual, but the reason for the error is that `\tabucline` needs an argument, i.e. `\tabucline{1-2}` etc.

The usage

```
\tabucline
\multirow{3}{*}{What Happened}
```

is wrong of course, since `\tabucline` grabs the (apparently) fragile command `\multirow`, (which does not even eject an error here then) and leaves `{3}{*}{What happened}` in the input, which is precisely setup, but not what was requested.

I can only guess, what was intended with `\tabucline` so I used `\tabucline{1-2}` (which has the same effect like `\hline` or `\midrule` etc. more or less here!)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}

\usepackage{tabu}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabu} to \textwidth { X[2,c] | X[3,c]}
  \toprule
  C1 &  C2 \\
  \tabucline{1-2}%
  \multirow{3}{*}{What Happened} & This is row 1 \\
  & This is row 2\\ 
  & This is row 3 \\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabu}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @FeiLi: You're welcome. Happy TeXing!